# How to add index to SQL: "where condition1 and ( condition2 or condition3)"?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I am using MySQL 5.7 and Ubuntu 18.

I have this SQL in my `slow.log`, it's slow ( about 10+s) and I want to add index for this SQL:

```
SELECT  `trades`.* 
FROM `trades` 
WHERE (market_id = 'vethusdt' and ( ask_member_id = 19 or bid_member_id = 19 ) ) 
ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 10;
```

I add 2 index for table "trades" :

index_trades_on_market_id_and_ask_member_id
index_trades_on_market_id_and_bid_member_id

but it seems useless.

How should I add index for it? thanks.

Comment: http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/function_based_indexes

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  MySQL 5.7, under Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An index which *might* help here would at least cover all the columns which appear in the `WHERE` clause:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON trades (market_id, ask_member_id, bid_member_id);
```

This assumes that your database would even choose to use the index, which it may not.

Answer (score 1):

You might find that this approach works better.  Rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM ((SELECT t.*
       FROM trades t
       WHERE t.market_id = 'vethusdt' AND t.ask_member_id = 19
       ORDER BY id DESC
       LIMIT 10
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT t.*
       FROM trades t
       WHERE t.market_id = 'vethusdt' AND t.bid_member_id = 19
       ORDER BY id DESC
       LIMIT 10
      )
     ) t
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Then you want two indexes:  `(market_id, ask_member_id, id)` and `(market_id, bid_member_id, id)`.

Comment: oh, seems a guru-level SQL... but I think this is a bit hard to read. thank you so much!

Comment: @SiweiShen申思维 . . . Are you saying that the performance of Tim's solution is better than this?

Comment: I don't know which is better. Your answer is great.